# Make jest works with expo

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, expo

In a fresh project based on the expo router template I can't get my tests to run. Looks like there is something missing from the jest.config.js or the babel.

Can I get any help on making it work? :)

My test:

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

describe('<App />', () => {
  it('has 1 child', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Output:

```
14 | import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/Accessib
            ^
error: Unexpected typeof
    at /Users/USER/PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/index.js:14:8

 0 pass
 1 fail
Ran 1 tests across 1 files. [13.00ms]
```

my settings:

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      ['babel-preset-expo', { jsxImportSource: 'nativewind' }],
      'nativewind/babel',
    ],
  };
};
```

PS: I tested removing nativewind and the problem persists.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".expo/types/**/*.ts", "expo-env.d.ts"]
}
```

package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ]
  },
...
"expo": "~50.0.7",
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
...
```